# CakePHP JavaScript execution with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, cakephp

I have a JavaScript in the view but it's not executing again after loading different content with AJAX, so I want to place it in the `<head>` of the view to be isolated from AJAX without having to put it in a file because it's using PHP arrays from the controller. How do I do it? Is there a way to write JavaScript code the CakePHP way and set it as inline false the same way as JavaScript files?

It seems like even JavaScript codes places in head will not execute with AJAX so how should I do it? Should I place JavaScript related divs outside the content div or what?

This is my view:

```
    <script>
    var geocoder, lat, lng;
    function initialize() {
        var location = <?php echo "\"" . $location . "\""?>;
        location = location.replace(/\+/g, ' ');
        document.getElementById("address").innerHTML = location + " Weather";
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $loc['lat'];?>, <?php echo $loc['lng'];?>);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 12,
            center: latlng,
            navigationControl: false,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            scaleControl: false,
            draggable: false,
            scrollwheel: false,
            disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
            zoomControl: false,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

        <?php $i = 0 ?>
        <?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
        var markerLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo h($post['Post']['latitude']); ?>, <?php echo h($post['Post']['longitude']); ?>);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: markerLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: '<?php echo h($post['Post']['temperature']); ?>',
        icon: 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_spin&chld=0.6|0|FF0000|12|_|<?php echo h($post['Post']['temperature']); ?>',
        url: '<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view', $post['Post']['id'])); ?>'
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            window.location.href = this.url;
        });
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    }

    function loadScript() {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBoEBzeiYi-bCaTIlcK7lrNKUyvUfLQqGM&sensor=false&callback=initialize&region=LB";
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".post .toggle").toggle(function(){
            $(".post .toggle").css('background-image','url(../../img/down.png)');
            $(this).css('background-image','url(../../img/up.png)');
            $(".post .description").hide();
            $(this).parent().find(".description").show("slow");
            $(".post").height(100);
            $(this).parent().height(200);},
            function() {$(".post .toggle").css('background-image','url(../../img/down.png)');$(".post").height(100);$(".post .description").hide();$(this).css('background-image','url(../../img/down.png)');
        });
    });

    window.onload = loadScript;
    </script>
    <div id="weather">
    <center><div id="address">&nbsp;</div>
    <p><div id="coords"><?php echo $loc['lat'] . ", " . $loc['lng'];?></div></p></center>
    <div id="weather-menu">
    <?php echo $this->Html->link('Today', 'today/' . $location);?>
    <?php echo $this->Html->link('Yesterday', 'yesterday/' . $location);?>
    <?php echo $this->Html->link('Custom', 'custom/' . $location);?>
    <?php echo $this->Html->link('All', 'all/' . $location);?>
    </div>
    <div id="post-container">
    <?php /*
    if ($posts) {
    echo "<div id=\"post\"><div id=\"temperature\">";
    echo $posts[0]['Post']['temperature'] . "°C</div>";
    if ($posts[0]['Humidity']['humidity'])
        echo "<div id=\"humidity\">" . $posts[0]['Humidity']['humidity'] . "%</div>";
    echo "<div id=\"created\">" . $this->Time->niceShort($posts[0]['Post']['created']) . "              </div>";
        echo "<div id=\"username\">" . $posts[0]['User']['username'] . "</div>";
        echo "<div id=\"condition\">";
        if (strtotime($posts[0]['Post']['created']) > date_sunrise(strtotime($posts[0]         ['Post']['created']), SUNFUNCS_RET_TIMESTAMP, $posts[0]['Post']['latitude'], $posts[0] ['Post']['longitude'],90, 2) && strtotime($posts[0]['Post']['created']) < date_sunset(strtotime($posts[0]['Post']['created']), SUNFUNCS_RET_TIMESTAMP, $posts[0]['Post']['latitude'], $posts[0]['Post']['longitude'],90, 2))      
        echo $this->Html->image('/img/weather-icons/' . $posts[0]['Post']['condition'] . 'A.png');
    else
        echo $this->Html->image('/img/weather-icons/' . $posts[0]['Post']['condition'] . 'B.png');
    echo "</div></div>";
}*/
?>
     <?php


    //$posts = $this->requestAction('/weather/fetch');
        foreach (array_slice($posts, 0) as $post) {
        echo "<div class=\"post\"><div class=\"temperature\">";
        echo $this->Html->link($post['Post']['temperature'] . "°C", array('controller' =>     'posts', 'action' => 'view', $post['Post']['id'])) . "</div>";
    if ($post['Humidity']['humidity'])
        echo "<div class=\"humidity\">" . $post['Humidity']['humidity'] . "%</div>";
    echo "<div class=\"created\">" . $this->Time->niceShort($post['Post']['created']) . "</div>";
    echo "<div class=\"username\">" . $this->Html->link($post['User']['username'], array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'view', $post['Post']['user_id'])) . "</div>";
    echo "<div class=\"condition\">";
    if (strtotime($post['Post']['created']) > date_sunrise(strtotime($post['Post']

['created']), SUNFUNCS_RET_TIMESTAMP, $post['Post']['latitude'], $post['Post']['longitude'],90, 2) && strtotime($post['Post']['created']) < date_sunset(strtotime($post['Post']['created']), SUNFUNCS_RET_TIMESTAMP, $post['Post']['latitude'], $post['Post']['longitude'],90, 2))      
        echo $this->Html->image('/img/weather-icons/' . $post['Post']['condition'] . 'A.png');
    else
        echo $this->Html->image('/img/weather-icons/' . $post['Post']['condition'] . 'B.png');
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<div class=\"description\">" . $post['Description']['description'] . "</div>";
    echo "<div class=\"toggle\"></div>";
    echo "</div>";
}
?>
</div>
<div id="side-container">
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<br/>
<div id ="current"><?php if (isset($w_temp)) echo "Current Temperature: " . $w_temp . "°C" . $this->Html->image('/img/wg.png');?></div>
</div>
<?php
$this->Paginator->options(array(
    'update' => '#content',
    'before' => $this->Js->get('#busy-indicator')->effect('fadeIn', array('buffer' => false)),
    'complete' => $this->Js->get('#busy-indicator')->effect('fadeOut', array('buffer' => false))
));
echo $this->Paginator->prev('« Previous ', null, null, array('class' => 'disabled'));
echo $this->Paginator->next('Next »', null, null, array('class' => 'disabled'));
echo $this->Js->writeBuffer();
?>
<div id="busy-indicator"></div>
</div>
```

and this is my controller index action:

```
public function index($date, $location = null) {
    $this->set('location', $location);
    $address = urlencode($location);
    $loc = $this->getLocation($address);
    $this->set('loc', $loc);
    $this->loadModel('Post');
    if ($date == 'all') {
        $this->paginate = array('conditions' => array(
                'latitude BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array(
                    $loc['lat'] - 0.05, $loc['lat'] + 0.05), 
                'longitude BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array(
                        $loc['lng'] - 0.05, $loc['lng'] + 0.05)
                ),
            'order' => array('Post.created' => 'desc'),
            'limit' => '5');
        $this->set('posts', $this->paginate('Post'));
    }
    else if ($date == 'today') {
        $this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'latitude BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array(
                    $loc['lat'] - 0.05, $loc['lat'] + 0.05), 
                'longitude BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array(
                        $loc['lng'] - 0.05, $loc['lng'] + 0.05),
                'Post.created >' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("-1 day"))
                ),
            'order' => array('Post.created' => 'desc'))));
    }
    else if ($date == 'yesterday') {
        $this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'latitude BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array(
                    $loc['lat'] - 0.05, $loc['lat'] + 0.05), 
                'longitude BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array(
                        $loc['lng'] - 0.05, $loc['lng'] + 0.05),
                'Post.created >' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("-2 day")),
                'Post.created <' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("-1 day"))
                ),
            'order' => array('Post.created' => 'desc'))));
    }
    $this->wunder($location);
}
```

Comment: If you include your code and markup, it helps in figuring out your problem. I suspect you're not running whatever script you're referring to when the elements it's accessing or referencing are available, ie, after the element is DOM ready. Also, if you're monitoring a Javascript console in the browser while the script runs, you might be missing errors that are occurring. I suggest Chrome Console or Firefox's Firebug console.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your first sentence "I have a JavaScript in the view but it's not executing with AJAX" Are you saying it's not executing with AJAX because of a problem or because you don't need it to? When you say "isolated from AJAX" do you mean aesthetically? You just want separate code blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you guys. I just needed to add this to my javascript code:

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
window.onload = loadScript;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: pathname,
        success: function(){
          loadScript();
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> I have a JavaScript in the view but it's not executing again after
>   loading different content with AJAX

I only briefly looked at what you are doing but I didn't immediately see where you are making an AJAX request. Clarifying that point would be helpful, as others have noted. However, be aware that After loading new content with AJAX if your script had event handlers on any replaced content then you will need to destroy and recreate the event handlers in Javascript (even if you replaced it with identical DOM elements).

To this point:

> Is there a way to write JavaScript code the CakePHP way and set it as
>   inline false the same way as JavaScript files?

So you do this essentially the same way as you reference external source files in cakePHP, you can replace:

```
<script>
...
</script>
```

with the following:

```
$this->Html->ScriptBlock('your javascript here', array('inline'=>false));
```

Then in the  section make sure you have (for cakePHP 2.1 or newer):

```
echo $this->fetch('script');
```

or (for cakePHP 2.0x or earlier)

```
$scripts_for_layout();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using "AJAX" to inject a script into a page i suppose, the way you are doing it is by using jQuery maybe or anything pulling your content into the DOM via element.innerHTML = content, am I wrong ?

BUT scripts passed in element.innerHTML will not execute, and this is what jQuery use to fragment your HTML response !

The best way to do it IMHO is to use "AJAX" only to get the data from your CakePHP app to the javascript front end (with a JSON response), then you will use this data within your javascript code to display your charts. It would be much more efficient, and you would not have the issues shoesole is talking about loosing DOM elements references.

Or you can do this the lazy way, with this hack :

```
<img style="display:none" src="data:image/png,script" onerror="
 console.log('Hey I am javascript code running as long as javascript isnt disabled!');
"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

// this is new invention like JSON  it seem cute function but it is not


function connect_php() {
jQuery(document).ready(function($){


    setTimeout(function() {
       $("#final_result").css('display', 'block');
    }, 4000); //here 1000 means 1 second

});

}

jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    (function a(x) {
        // The following condition
        // is the base case.
        if ( ! x) {
            return;
        }
        a(--x);
        event.preventDefault();
        $( "#aform" ).submit();
        connect_php();
    })(10);
    
});



</script>
```

if you have php for loop doing something must wait this will fired after php finish or your loop finish send message from php to JavaScript defined in JS from start